# use jquery to add class both on click of nav item AND scroll past div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I am looking to use jquery to add a class of "selected" both on clicking of a nav item as well as scrolling past that section div.

So far I have got the class added on clicking of the nav item but I am unsure how to neatly add the same affect when scrolling past each section div.

Here's my script for adding the class on click (which is pretty straightforward and standard):

```
$('#fixednav li').click(function(){
$('#fixednav li').removeClass("selected");
$(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

...It all works great when user clicks the items in the fixed menu. But how do I add the selected class when user just scrolls down the page without using the fixed menu? Each section has a div id so I would think it would be easy to add something in to add the class on scroll past the div id....

[Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbPM9/3/)

Scroll down a bit to see the fixed nav pop in....

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i used scrollspy to fix it here is the link and demo on bootstrap :

[scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

if you get some pb please let me know.

Comment: I am not using bootstrap here...can I still use scrollspy?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/8KSsU/)

This is the js used, check the fiddle for html and css.

```
var hei = $("#header").height();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > hei){
            $("#header").addClass('fixed');
            $('.body-wrapper').css('margin-top',hei);
        }else{
            $("#header").removeClass('fixed');
            $('.body-wrapper').css('margin-top','0');
        }
    });
    $("#header li a").on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var header_height = $("#header").height();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-header_height
        }, 1000);
    });

    var aChildren = $("#header li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
    var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
    for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
        var aChild = aChildren[i];
        var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
        aArray.push(ahref);
    } // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
        var docHeight = $(document).height();


        for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
            var theID = aArray[i];
            var divPos = $(theID).offset().top-hei-30; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
            var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
            if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("nav-active");
            } else {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: So you are saying don't even use the on click script and only have the selected class added based on window position? What if the text in each section changes? I'll need to adjust my script if more or less text is added to the sections?

Comment: You can use the click event. Even if you add or reduce the text in each section it should be fine, you don't have to adjust the script because the positions of each sections are calculated using the script.